# How do I "Scope to this" every time I start Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm working with Unity3D and I'd like to always start up Visual Studio 2015 scoped to my scripts folder. Is there any way to make this happen?

[Screenshot of my Solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfjZm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the solution explorer to automatically track the currently open file it should go straight into yours scripts folder.

This is how you set it up:

```
Tools >
  Options >
    Projects and Solutions >
      General >
        Track Active Item In Solution Explorer
```